# pandas rolling window aggregating string column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I am struggling when computing string aggregation operation using rolling window on pandas.

I am given the current df, where *t_dat is* the purchase date, *customer_id* and *article_id* are self-explanatory.

| t_dat | customer_id | article_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-04-24 | 486230 | 781570001 |
| 2020-04-24 | 486230 | 598755030 |
| 2020-04-27 | 486230 | 836997001 |
| 2020-05-02 | 486230 | 687707005 |
| 2020-06-03 | 486230 | 741356002 |

and I'd like to **group by customer_id** and concatenate articles id over a weekly rolling window (e.g. *article_ids* column in table below. pandas doesn't seem to support rolling window aggregation for string columns therefore I tried resample, but it doesn't accomplish what I expect (look at table below for my expected result)

| t_dat | customer_id | article_id | article_ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-04-24 | 486230 | 781570001 | 598755030 836997001 |
| 2020-04-24 | 486230 | 598755030 | 781570001 836997001 |
| 2020-04-27 | 486230 | 836997001 | 836997001 687707005 |
| 2020-05-02 | 486230 | 687707005 | 687707005 |
| 2020-06-03 | 486230 | 741356002 | 741356002 |

My goal is to actually understand if there are purchase pattern among different article_ids (i.e. are some articles bought shortly after any client has purchased another article?)

To make it more explicit, I am trying to structure the problem in two steps:

1. What are the articles that a customer has purchased within 7 days from any other article purchase? I want to repeat this exercise for each customer and each purchased product
2. Once this is done, I want to identify those articles that are purchased more frequently in combination (within one week) from other products, so I can build a basic rec system.

Here I am looking for a solution to number 1.

I have tried both

```
df.groupby('customer_id').rolling('7D', on = 't_dat', min_periods = 1)['article_id'].agg(' '.join).reset_index()
```

or

```
df.groupby('customer_id').rolling('7D', on = 't_dat', min_periods = 1)['article_id'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index()
```

and, using resample,

```
df.groupby('customer_id').resample('7D', on = 't_dat')['article_id'].agg(' '.join).reset_index()
```

without success. First one because of error **TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found** and, when I cast string type to *article_id*, it returns **TypeError: must be real number, not str**;
second attempt because it doesn't return what I need with the proper offset (it takes week intervals starting from first occurrence in the dataset and then keep on setting the weekly intervals without rolling offset)

I have coded an alternative but it looks extremely slow and I would leverage on pandas vectorized operations to speed it up:

```
# for each article_id in every purchase, I want to check which other articles where bought within the following week

articles_list = df.groupby(['customer_id', 't_dat'])['article_id'].apply(list).reset_index()

def get_recommendations():

    dict_recs = {}

    for n, row in df.iterrows():
        customer = row['customer_id']
        date_purchase = row['t_dat']
        articles_purchase = row['article_id']
        df_clean = df[(df['customer_id'] == customer) & (df['t_dat'] <= date_purchase + timedelta(days=7)) & (df['t_dat'] >= date_purchase)]
        articles_to_recommend = df_clean['article_id']
        
        print("Iterating over {} row".format(n))
        # print("Articles in scope are {} \n".format(articles_to_recommend))
        
        for article in articles_purchase:
            articles_list_to_iter = [i[j] for i in articles_to_recommend for j in range(len(i)) if i[j] != article]
            # print("Articles preprocessed are {} \n".format(articles_list_to_iter))
            if article not in dict_recs:
                dict_recs[article] = articles_list_to_iter
            else:
                dict_recs[article].extend(articles_list_to_iter)
    
    recs_list = {k: Counter(v).most_common(12) for k, v in dict_recs.items()}

    return recs_list
```

Can you suggest any alternative I can use to accomplish what I am looking for?

Comment: I think `df.groupby('customer_id').rolling('7D', on = 't_dat', min_periods = 1)['article_id'].agg(' '.join).reset_index()` best describes what I am trying to accomplish. It's not really an aggregation because the final df still has the same number of rows of source df, but the computation must be pursued separately for each customer_id --> hence the groupby('customer_id').

Comment: Minimum number of observations in window required to have a value; otherwise, result is np.nan.

anyway the parameter is not really important in my scenario because there are no NaN in the dataset, so we can omit that

Comment: I have also included the description in the original question, I think it should be clear now. I am trying to structure the problem in two steps:

1. What are the articles that a customer has purchased within 7 days from any other article purchase? I want to repeat this exercise for each customer and each purchased product
2. Once this is done, I want to identify those articles that are purchased more frequently in combination (within one week) from other products, so I can build a basic rec system.

Here I am looking for a solution to number 1.

Comment: I used pd.grouper to get an answer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to aggregate by the day. Create a second dataframe and accumulate by customer all articles per day.  Use the pd.Grouper to create your 7 day rolling window!

```
data="""
t_dat   customer_id article_id
2020-04-24  486230  781570001
2020-04-24  486230  598755030
2020-04-27  486230  836997001
2020-05-02  486230  687707005
2020-06-03  486230  741356002
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\t')
df['t_dat'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t_dat'])
df = df.sort_values(by=['t_dat'])
#grouped = df.groupby(['t_dat', 'customer_id']).agg({'article_id': lambda x: list(x)})

#grouped=grouped.reset_index()
#df=pd.DataFrame(grouped)
df = df.set_index('t_dat')
print(df)
df = df.groupby(['customer_id', pd.Grouper(level='t_dat', freq='7D')])['article_id'].apply(list).reset_index()
print(df)
```

output:

```
customer_id      t_dat                         article_id
0       486230 2020-04-24  [781570001, 598755030, 836997001]
1       486230 2020-05-01                        [687707005]
2       486230 2020-05-29                        [741356002]
```